# Struts2 - Including a jsp according to the bean values

Tags: jsp, struts2, javabeans

I need a sort of page switch on Struts2.

Like (on index.jsp) `if myBean.String="main" include main.jsp else include welcome.jsp`

I tried with `<s:if>` or `<c:choose>` but looks that they can evalutate only boolean. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the Struts2 part, but you can just use EL in [`<jsp:include>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref2020.html#8828).

```
<jsp:include page="${bean.pagename}.jsp" />
```

As to the JSTL `<c:if>` or `<c:choose>` tags, you can just compare strings in EL as follows (like as in JSF which you're already familiar with, according to your question history! ;) ):

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${bean.pagename == 'main'}">
        <jsp:include page="main.jsp" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <jsp:include page="welcome.jsp" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

If it are only 2 conditions, then you can also use the conditional operator `?:`:

```
<jsp:include page="${bean.pagename == 'main' ? 'main' : 'welcome'}.jsp}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Java EE 5 tutorial - Examples of EL expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaim)

Comment: Uhm...maybe it can rocks. Just i don't know how to set a name of a Bean on Struts2. Seems that is impossible :)

Comment: It's definitely possible (Struts2 also runs on top of Servlet API, like JSF). I only don't know in detail how to do it, since I've never used Struts2.

Comment: As a suggest : don't use this FRAMEWORK :) JSF is 100 times better for what i saw...

Comment: Struts2 is indeed vintage. Did you know that a former committer of Struts, Ed Burns, was around 2003 hired by Sun to do the JSF works? Although the first JSF versions were horrible as well, JSF 2.0 is simply insane.

Comment: anyway, searching on internet, looks like NOBODY know how to declare name/scope of the beans in Struts2, that's why i said "seems is not possible"... :)

Comment: I *think* you need to let your action class implement [`ServletRequestAware`](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.2/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ServletRequestAware.html) to put a bean in request scope by `request.setAttribute("bean", bean)` inside action method. Or implement [`SessionAware`](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.2/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/SessionAware.html) to put bean in session scope by `session.setAttribute("bean", bean)`.

Comment: That's horrible :) Doing this i need to manage each session/bean/attribute manually. Not so different to use PHP at this point...

Comment: BalusC : don't forget this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304763/jsf-problem-with-viewscope :)